# Saving text labels on top of images

Tags: xcode, swift, image, xcode7

I'm building an app which takes Strings from the user and saves them using NSUserDefaults. Then I recover them and paste them on top of an image (a form or questionnaire)  I'm currently saving the image with .write to file but when I check the image I've saved, I discovered that it doesn't save the full image and as a consequence the positions for the fields aren't right. I need to be able to send this image and later on print on a sheet of A4 paper.

The simulator :
http://postimg.org/image/5szujdgw3/

The saved image:
http://postimg.org/image/uq6mea6vb/

Why isn't it saving the full image?

Here's my code :

```
import UIKit

class StartMorgagesSave: UIViewController {
  let rectangle = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRectMake(80, 166, 80, 05)) //x , y , width , height 240, 165
  let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
  //let label = UILabel()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    shapeLayer.path = rectangle.CGPath
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    view.pdfData.writeToURL(NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first!.URLByAppendingPathComponent("test53.pdf"), atomically: true) // what it is saved as
    view.pdfData.writeToFile("fdfdlo", atomically: false)
    print(NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first!.path!)     
  }
  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }
}

extension UIView {
  var pdfData: NSData {
    let result = NSMutableData()
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(result, frame, nil)
    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return result }
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage()
    layer.renderInContext(context)
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()
    return result
  }
}
```

Niall

Comment: Have you added a constraints to the view? Seems like you haven't.

Comment: I have, centre Horizontally to superview, Top space to top layout guide, Equal Width to superview, equal height to superview set  to the image view @Hoh

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/p2ajsz20f/ @Hoh